# Cannot install uwsgi thru pip install uwsgi using pycharms in Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, uwsgi

Getting an error installing uWsgi using pycharms. I do not have Linux and most of the solutions I saw are using Linux. Any advice?

Executed command:
pip install uwsgi

Error occurred:
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Command output:
Collecting uwsgi
Using cached uWSGI-2.0.19.1.tar.gz (803 kB)

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Users\Sherman\Selenium\video_code\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Sherman\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kmyfu2dr\\uwsgi_af87984b16b348968367e4dff1c9d244\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Sherman\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kmyfu2dr\\uwsgi_af87984b16b348968367e4dff1c9d244\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Sherman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-1cos39nx'
     cwd: C:\Users\Sherman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kmyfu2dr\uwsgi_af87984b16b348968367e4dff1c9d244\
Complete output (7 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Sherman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kmyfu2dr\uwsgi_af87984b16b348968367e4dff1c9d244\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    import uwsgiconfig as uc
  File "C:\Users\Sherman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kmyfu2dr\uwsgi_af87984b16b348968367e4dff1c9d244\uwsgiconfig.py", line 8, in <module>
    uwsgi_os = os.uname()[0]
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'uname'
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work on windows 10, you will have to build uWSGI package by modifying some of its setup. Replacing `os` with `platform`

Alternatively, you can try `waitress` or `uvicorn`. Which work well in windows.